DigitalOcean Spaces and Django/Wagtail - SSL error on upload
I have a Django/Wagtail app running on DigitalOcean AppPlatform and am trying to enable Spaces for media storage. The app builds just fine, but image uploads from the app fail every time with the following error:
[2024-04-17 21:40:33] botocore.exceptions.SSLError: SSL validation failed for https://mybucket.mybucket.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/original_images/Screenshot_2024-04-01_at_2.10.53PM.png hostname 'mybucket.mybucket.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com' doesn't match either of '*.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com', 'nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com'

That URL shows my bucket name repeated twice (note "mybucket.mybucket"), but I can't tell where or why it's repeating.
In my production.py settings file, I'm using env vars set on the DigitalOcean side, and have triple checked that those vars are correct. I've also tried hardcoding them instead just to be sure, with the same error.
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv('SPACES_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv('SPACES_SECRET_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.getenv('SPACES_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read' 
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = os.getenv('SPACES_ENDPOINT_URL')
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = os.getenv('SPACES_REGION')
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
  'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = 's3v4'
AWS_S3_ADDRESSING_STYLE = 'virtual'
AWS_LOCATION = os.getenv('SPACES_FOLDER')

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
MEDIA_URL = '%s/' % (AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL)

And my config vars set on the DigitalOcean side:
SPACES_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXXXX
SPACES_SECRET_KEY=XXXXXX
SPACES_BUCKET_NAME=mybucket
SPACES_ENDPOINT_URL=https://mybucket.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com
SPACES_REGION=nyc3
SPACES_FOLDER=static

Removing the bucket name from the ENDPOINT_URL as suggested (so that it is just https://mybucket.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com results in a SignatureDoesNotMatch error.
I've added & installed the following in the app (including storages under INSTALLED_APPS):

boto3 (v1.34.84)
botocore (v1.34.84)
django-storages (v1.14.2)

And have a storages_backends.py with the following:
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage

class StaticStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
  location = 'static'


class MediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
  location = ''

Any ideas on what is causing that hostname URL to be malformed?

I am not familiar with spaces. Any chance the duplication is coming from AWS_LOCATION = os.getenv('SPACES_FOLDER')

endpoint_url should not contain bucket name

@iklinac - I suspected the same, but removing that from the endpoint fails as well.
